# View entries that are not in "My Contacts" in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

Is there a simple way to filter only contacts that are not currently in the "My Contacts" section, and only appear in "All Contacts"?
I usually get tons of clutter in there, and I like to remove unneeded entries, but so far have only been able to go over them one by one, and when the "Move to My Contacts" button becomes enabled, I know this is a contact I may safely delete (Or permanently keep).

Is there a better way to do this, using the simple web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Google Contacts (in Gmail, not the stand alone page, for now), has the "Other Contacts" section which contains exactly those that were automatically added.